# what is the difference between simulation and estimation?

Tags: statistics, markov-chains, mcmc

Iam not getting any clarity while implementing markovchain montocarlo simulation and also difference between simulation and estimation .please help me with this?

Comment: Try stats.stackexchange.com instead, this is off topic for SO. Be sure to include your own analysis when you ask the question.